# деревья или массив?

Tags: c++, структуры-данных

В каких случаях возникают преимущества структур данных, основанных на массивах, перед теми, что основаны на деревьях, кроме индексации?

Comment: Странный вопрос. А к какой категории вы отнесли бы дерево, в узлах которого массивы?

Comment: @D-side согласен, вопрос скорее носит не столь общий , сколько более конкретный характер, в ходе реализации своей программы использовал в основе массив для хранения чисел, решил глянуть сложность структур для хранения данных по статейке на хабре, и честно говоря не увидел никаких преимуществ массива перед деревьями по оценкам, кроме индексации, отсюда и вопрос

Comment: Вы сейчас нисколько не конкретизировали вопрос.

Comment: @D-side хорошо попробую иначе, перед вами задача, хранить числа в Х структуре данных с максимальной выгоде по производительности, по каким параметрам вы бы выбирали X ?

Comment: Чисто математически, максимальная выгода по производительности будет для того контейнера, для которого минимальна сумма по  операциям, которые в этой задаче совершаются, их `частоты * ресурсопотребления`.  Вы это ищете?

Comment: @D-side ну что то примерное, спасибо